# How to transfer the amount to two different merchants in single transaction using authorize.net?

Tags: php, authorize.net

We are using authorize.net as payment gateway and we need to send the amount to two different merchants in single transaction. In order to achieve it, we are using the below code.

```
<?php
require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php';
define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "12345");
define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "abcde");
define("AUTHORIZENET_SANDBOX", true); 
$sale = new AuthorizeNetAIM; 
 $amount = $_POST['ordertotal'];
 $bill_to_cardholder = $_POST['bill_to_cardholder'];
 $bill_to_card_number = trim($_POST['bill_to_card_number']);
 $bill_to_cvv2 = $_POST['bill_to_cvv2'];
 $exp_date = $_POST['bill_to_exp_month'].$_POST['bill_to_exp_year'];
 //add information to authorize
 $sale->first_name = $_SESSION['bill_to_first_name'];
 $sale->last_name=$_SESSION['bill_to_last_name']; 
$response1 = $sale->authorizeOnly($amount,$bill_to_card_number,$exp_date);
if ($response1->approved)  { 
  define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "678910");  define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "fghij"); 
 $response2 = $sale->authorizeOnly($amount,$bill_to_card_number,$exp_date);
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($response2); exit;
}
?>
```

But here the problem is that first transaction is completed successfully and second one is denied. Because, once the constant is defined, we could not able to overwrite through PHP script. We have tried by defining as variable for the parameters that supposed to pass on authorize.net such as `$AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID` and `$AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY` but the authorize.net not accepted the normal variables. Could anyone please provide the solution how to transfer the amount to two different merchants in single transaction using authorize.net? Thanks.

Comment: As the name suggests, a "constant" is exactly that, a constant value that cannot be changed during the execution of your script. Using variables should work, however. Why is Authorize.net rejecting it / what response are you getting?

Comment: If it is being rejected as a duplicate (which it shouldn't, because you're changing the credentials), try setting the `x_duplicate_window` field to `0`, according to [this page](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A425).

Comment: It is currently not possible to split payment across multiple merchant accounts using Authorize.Net.